# jquery.support to detect JavaScript's File API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fileapi

I can't find the way to detect if the browser supports the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) through the [`.support`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) methon in jQuery.

Anyone knows it?

(Incidentally: a way to detect the size of a file in `input[type=file]` with IE?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not seem to be implementd in jQuery, but you could check yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/RCz3s/.

The `files` property of an `<input type='file'>` returns an empty `FileList` if it's implemented, and otherwise it is not defined (i.e. it is `undefined`).

```
var support = (function(undefined) {
    return $("<input type='file'>")    // create test element
                 .get(0)               // get native element
                 .files !== undefined; // check whether files property is not undefined
})();
```

Comment: More readable would be to check with `typeof` 
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `typeof $("<input type='file'>").get(0).files != "undefined"`

Answer (score 10):

Another way to check is just by checking the presence of the [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) types:

```
var FileApiSupported = !!('File' in window &&
                          'FileReader' in window &&
                          'FileList' in window &&
                          'Blob' in window);
```

Comment: I tested in firefox 22 that claims to have full support of this API and this solution didn't work. I don't know about others browsers.

Comment: `var FileApiSupported = !!(window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)` to get a boolean value