# jQuery check if browser can read file type on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to check if a browser can read file type when the page loads.

With on input change it's:

```
$('input[name=photo]').change(function(e) {
   var file = e.target.files[0];

   var type = file.type;
   alert(type);
});
```

But how to check it on page load? I need it because browsers which can't do that can't resize images client side so I'm gonna load the normal upload form on pageload if that's the case.

Comment: Is that what you want?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361072/jquery-support-to-detect-javascripts-file-api

Comment: And which files file type it should check?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr images, to make it more clear please read my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618651/jquery-ajax-image-upload-check-browser-support

Comment: @epascarello That could be it, I'm gonna check it with all kinds of browsers now

Comment: @epascarello Unfortunately it returns true on android browser but this browser cant read the type on file change, any other idea?